# R: How to work around this error index in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that decreases each loop one column, and another 'b' matrix that every loop keeps the values ​​of the column that was lost from the matrix 'a'. The problem is that when the matrix is left with only one column it can not be accessed over this way `a [,1]` then get the error `Error in a[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions` . Any way to get around this?

```
a<- matrix(2,4,4);
b<- matrix(numeric(0),nrow(a),2);

i<- 1;

for ( i in 1:(ncol(a)-1)){
  a<- a[,1]*a[,-1];
  b[,i]<- a[,1];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the result of an index on a matrix results in a single vector, the default behavior is to drop the dimensions and just return a simple vector. If you want to preserve the "matrix-ness" of the result, you need to add `drop=F` to the indexing

```
a<- matrix(2,4,4);
b<- matrix(numeric(0),nrow(a),3);

i<- 1;

for ( i in 1:(ncol(a)-1)){
  a<- a[,1]*a[,-1, drop=F];
  b[,i]<- a[,1];
}
```